# IIS Multithreading

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I have a web application under IIS 7.  There is a page with `Button1`. When I click this `Button1` the following method fires:

```
string url = "http://example.com";

string resultStr = "";

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

string encoding = resp.CharacterSet;
if (encoding.Equals(String.Empty)) encoding = "UTF-8";

Stream strResponse = resp.GetResponseStream();

int bytesSize = 0, c = 0;
byte[] downBuffer = new byte[2048];//2kb

while ((bytesSize = strResponse.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    if (++c > 100) break;//200kb - max
    downBuffer = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding), Encoding.UTF8, downBuffer);

    string tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
    resultStr += tempString;
}

strResponse.Close();

TextBox1.Text = resultStr;
```

As you can see TextBox1 will contain html code of remote page.

There is a problem: while this method is running I can't load other pages! How to solve this problem?

I know that there is an application pool which store application threads so server can process several threads at the same time... But it doesn't works for me. Why?

Comment: Do you mean that while this code is running you cann't open a second tab and load pages from the same application? Or do you mean that the current page doesn't reload until after the code is finished? The first would be strange, the second is by design.

Comment: I mean the first. And it's strange for me too...
When I open the second tab, another page wouldn't appear while the request from the first page is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you are using Session in your application, do you? Session is not thread-safe. This means that if you are using Session, ASP.NET locks the entire request and doesn't allow other requests (**from the same Session**) to run in parallel. Requests from the same session run sequentially. You can have multiple requests from different sessions running in parallel though.

In fact it's a little more subtle than that. ASP.NET uses a ReaderWriterLock to synchronize access to the session object, meaning that you can have 2 requests from the same session that are only reading from it run in parallel, but as long as you have a write access to the session it will block other parallel requests from the same session.

You could control this using the `EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"` in your page to indicate that it is only reading from the session and thus allow for parallel execution of requests.

Comment: I've opened another browser with the second page. It works fine because in the second browser there is another Session.

thx you a lot!

Comment: @user1025125, glad I could help. Is there something else you would like to ask or maybe you could consider closing this thread?